# Is this a good approach to select the database based on the user?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing a system using ASP.NET MVC + WebAPI + AngularJS which has the following property: users can log in and different users have totally different data. The reason is simple: the system allows management of data, but although the schema is the same for everyone, the data is totally disconnected between users. Even because of organization, consistency and security, each user would need one separate database.

This gives rise to a problem: although every single database should be the same, i.e., same tables and columns, and hence same EF Data Context, the connections are different. This confuses me because I'm used to specify the connection string on the config XML file and this couldn't be done here, since the connection string would be dynamic.

I've then thought about a solution, which I doesn't now if it's the best one: I create one repository, which in it's construction receives the username of the logged in user. Then, the repository goes on the database of the system and looks for the connection data for that logged in user (this data would be informed when the user registers). Then the repository builds then connection string and feeds it into the `DbContext`.

Is this a good approach to this problem? Or there are more recommended ways to deal with this kind of thing? Security is one important concern here, and because of that I'm unsure of my approach.

Comment: "each user would need one separate database" - this is your problem.  There's absolutely no reason why you would need a separate database for each user. That's just crazy. The whole point of a relational database is that you create relationships between relevant records. You don't create separate databases for distinct sets of data.

Comment: I think you're talking about Multitenancy here? Security of each tenants data can be achieved in a number of places, one of which is having separate databases. Have you considered using one database though, and employing Data access rights per tenant?

Comment: @AntP the reason is the following: each user uses the system to manage data about his specific company. Because of that if the system has 10 users, it seems better to each user have it's own table of products, it's own table of customers and so on. Since are different companies using the system, it seemed better to me to keep the data apart like that even to avoid too big tables that would continue to grow a lot as new users come. RussCam, do you think this approach you suggested is better even considering this point I said? Sorry if I said nonsense, I'm not very experient with databases yet.

Comment: Still sounds like a single-database job to me. Relate company information to company records via a `CompanyId` column. Again, this is what relational databases are designed for.

Comment: I'd concur with Ant P; start with arguably the simpler solution, one database. Splitting out into multiple databases from the get-go may be making life more difficult for yourself when it comes to ensuring all customers databases are kept up to date, etc. Sure, you gain some security by isolating data in separate databases but I would question if that was *really* necessary.

Comment: I see the point: I start with the simpler solution and if the system grows and the amount of data starts to become difficult to manage then I seek another solution like multiple databases. Thanks for the help AntP and Russ Cam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Data Context in an Entity Framework solution has a constructor overload that allows you to specify a connection string.  You can find out how to build and use that connection string at the link below.

**Reference**
[How to: Build an EntityConnection Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

That said, unless you have very special requirements, it's much better from a maintenance and operational standpoint to simply put a UserID in the appropriate tables, and filter on the currently logged in User ID.

Answer (score 0):

One database per user seems like a crazy solution to me.

Include a `user_id` column in tables that contain *per user* data and filter on it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how complex your per-user database will be. If we are talking about 5-10 tables, then it is easier to add, manage and query addition ID column for all tables, than it is to manage multiple databases. But the more complex the model will get and the more tables will be in the database, then it becomes much easier just to have one database per user compared to having one more column for each table and having to add the user checks to all your queries. Especially the more complicated ones.

Same goes for performance. If you are expecting user databases to grow large in volume of data, then having separate databases could allow you to scale horizontally by putting different databases into different servers.

Shared database will also pose a problem if user requests raw access into their data. And it can happen, for example when they want to migrate the data.